# I am not able to export image in CSV file in Django Admin

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-admin

Every time I export the data all of it gets exported but for the image which is there I am only getting the url of the image and not actual image.

Image of exported CSV file

[image]

Database fields from where I export it

[image]

I want the actual image to be exported in CSV file and not the image storage path.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please edit your question to include code demonstrating your approach to this problem so far.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot save files in the database and you can only save the address where they are stored.
But there is one way, and that is to convert the files to a base64 format and save them as a string or text.